# tensorflow import vgg16 failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I just do not understand why I have already downloaded the vgg16, and it still comes up with ImportError: No module named 'download'. My directory shows on the right top of the image.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't named your own file with `vgg16.py` as it will cause collision problem. Rename you filename and try again :)

Comment: Where did you get the vgg16.py source file?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you downloaded vgg16.py [from here](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials).

It seems there is a download.py module in that repository that goes with vgg16.py.

Perhaps you should download the whole repo and put your 0618.py script inside the repo root and run it from there?